# Как сохранить добавленный класс в local storage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

есть такой скрипт

```
for (let i = 0; i < addToCart.length; i++) {
    addToCart[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
        addToCart[i].classList.add('disable');
    })
}
```

который выполняет определенную функцию и плюс накидывает по кликнутому элементу класс disable.

Этот класс скрывает кликнутую кнопку, необходимо сохранить это состояние при перезагрузке страницы и при переходах с других страниц, мне нужна реализация на фронте, без бэка.

Comment: сохранить класс? а зачем?

Comment: Того требует задача, необходимо сохранить состояние объекта, чтоб при перезагрузки страницы это состояние сохранялось

Comment: сохранить состояние объекта !== сохранить класс

Comment: Можно более развернутый ответ) спасибо)

Comment: При таком вопросе, в котором ничего не указано, по сути - нет)

Comment: Самое простое - дать id элементу (или id родителя) и сохранять для него класс (набор классов) localStorage.setItem('id','class' );

Answer (score 0):

Когда юзер кликнет, мы запишем ему такой ключ:

```
localStorage.setItem('isClick', true)
```

Затем мы можем проверить, установлен ли этот ключ у юзера, и если да, то поставим класс:

```
const userSession = localStorage.isClick('notFirstSession')

if (userSession) {
    document.querySelector('button').classList.add('disable')
}
```

Я позал вам общий алгоритм действий, без конкрертных примеров как определять клик и элемент – с этим, думаю, вы справитесь сами.